# Show the solution of a scalar SDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

I am currently self-studying some financial mathematics and am stuck on a practice problem:

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBscT.png)

I have defined the below as hinted

\begin{align}
Y_t &= x_0 e^{\alpha t} \\
Z_t &= \sigma e^{\alpha t} \\
R_t &= \int_{0}^{t} e^{-\alpha s} dWt
\end{align}

and then computed Ito's rule on

\begin{align}
F(y,z,r) &= y + zr \\
dX_t &= d(y + zr) \\
&= dY_t + rdZ_t + zdR_t + dZ_tdR_t
\end{align}

which for me simplified to

$$dX_t = \alpha e^{\alpha t} x_0 + \alpha \sigma e^{\alpha t} \int_{0}^{t} e^{-\alpha s} \,dWs + \sigma e^{\alpha(t-s)}dWt + \alpha \sigma e^{\alpha(t-s)}dW_t$$

I'm not sure if I had applied multi-dimensional Ito's formula properly or if I had missed a term.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is wrong in your last line.

Why you use lower case $r,z\,$? This should be

\begin{align}\require{cancel}
dX_t &= dY_t + R_t\,dZ_t + Z_t\,dR_t + dZ_t\,dR_t\\[2mm]
&=\alpha\, x_0\,e^{\alpha t}\,dt+\alpha\,\sigma\, e^{\alpha t}\Big(\int_0^te^{-\alpha s}\,dW_s\Big)\,\color{red}{dt}+\sigma\,\cancel{e^{\alpha t}\,e^{-\alpha t}}\,dW_t\,.\tag{1}
\end{align}
There is no $dZ_t\,dR_t$ term because $Z$ is of finite variation.
Using
$$\tag{2}
X_t=e^{\alpha t}x_0+\sigma\,e^{\alpha t}\int_0^te^{-\alpha s}\,dW_s\,.
$$

The equation (1) can be written as
$$\tag{3}
dX_t=\alpha\,X_t\,dt+\sigma\,dW_t\,.
$$